# 'quser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell

When using quser in powershell script to get information about user sessions on a remote desktop sesison host, an error occured which says `The term 'quser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`. The code is something like this,

```
$hostObject = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($ip) | Select-Object HostName
$hostName = $hostObject.HostName
$hostInformation = quser /server:$hostName
```

How to make powershell recognize quser?

Comment: Have you tried typing out the full path of quser.exe?

Comment: That is what i am looking for! I don't know full path of quser.

Comment: I found the path to be C:\Windows\System32\quser.exe, but when executing it, this doesn't seem to work either. 
"The term 'C:\Windows\System32\quser.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Comment: `&"C:\windows\System32\quser.exe"`. If you do this multiple times, it's better to use `$quser = "C:\windows\System32\quser.exe"` and `&$quser`.

Comment: Using this method, I get `The term 'C:\Windows\System32\quser.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet` ... Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe difference between x64 and x32? ... Nvm same result...

Answer (score 0):

The command quser is not found in 32 bit PowerShell. It only works in 64 bit. I have used quser in Windows 10 64 bit 22H2 Enterprise version. Quser doesn't work in Windows 10 Home version.

If you use PowerShell script eg. in Intune installation .intunewin package, add following lines to you script.

```
if ($env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 -eq "AMD64") {
    write-warning "WARNING: 32bit PowerShell, starting x64 PowerShell session and continue"
    if ($myInvocation.Line) {
        &"$env:WINDIR\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile $myInvocation.Line
    }else{
        &"$env:WINDIR\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile -file "$($myInvocation.InvocationName)" $args
    }
exit $lastexitcode
}
```

Source: https://www.vroege.biz/?p=3970

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are trying to run this command on a server and not a workstation. I have tried to run on from my laptop and it didn't work but always works when I run it on a server.